# Как определить категорию и подкатегорию продукта в карточке товара OpenCart 2.1.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0

Есть проблемная задача OpenCart 2.1.0.2.

**Нужно добиться следующего результата:**
Важно, чтобы URL продукта был такой (используется Seo url) -> имя_домена.com/*2234566*,
при этом хлебные крошки должны выглядеть так (полный путь к товару):
*Главная > Категория 1 > Категория 2 > Категория 3 > Название товара.*

**Проблема:**
Как я понимаю, хлебные крошки формируются из url, и в данном url нет необходимых параметров для определения всех категорий.

Извращаясь над данной задачей, я добился этого результата так: находясь на странице категории, сохраняю крошки в куку, а в карточке продукта их отображаю. Проблема в том, что если я перейду на товар по ссылке НЕ из категории (например из поисковика или мессенджера), или открою в браузере несколько товаров, тогда либо вообще не увижу крошек, либо они будут для всех страниц одинаковые.

**Вопрос**
Как еще, более правильно и надежно, можно определить категорию товара находясь на странице продукта?

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте в контроллере продукта функция `$this->request->get['path']` должна отдавать вам строку из всех категорий в порядке вложенности, соответственно разбиваете по разделителю и через функцию `$this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat_id)` строите крошки.
2. В модели продукта есть функция `$this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id)`, она вам тоже отдаст все категории связанные с продуктом, для получения:

   ```
   $product_id = $this->request->get['product_id'];
   ```